# Extending Java classes with different subclasses

Tags: java, class, inheritance, super

In Java you cannot extend multiple super classes. But can you have multiple sub classes extend to a single super class?

1)
For example:

```
Class A {}

Class B extends A {}

Class C extends A {}

Class D extends A {}
```

So different sub classes from a single super class.

2)
Or do you have to do it hierarchal no matter what?

```
Class A {}

Class B extends A {}

Class C extends B {}

Class D extends C {}
```

Is it #1 or #2? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All classes extend from Object (either directly or via superclasses), so yes. [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can choose anyone as per your requirement, both ways possible.

Answer (score 0):

Nice discovery. So what?

It all depends on what you want to do... 
If you have a class **Animal** than that class might be subclassed by different other classes like **Dog**, **Elephant**, **Cat** etc..

```
class Animal{}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
```

and so on...

The other case is suitable for other situations. Like my MyClass1 which extends Object  is extended by MyClass2 etc..

Just read about **Inheritance**. That's it.